# MS-Access split database with some shared physical tables

Tags: ms-access, split

**Edit.** I have been told that my question is too broad in scope and is likely to result in opinion-based answers. I disagree but anyway, in an attempt to get this question accepted as valid, here is a synopsis:

Is it possible to have a split MS Access database where some of the tables are physically common across several back-ends? By physically common, I mean that some of the physical tables are shared. This would allow admin users to update fields in relatively data-stable tables in one back end instance so that the updates are seen across all back end instances. At the same time, most of the back end tables would remain separate, so that changes to that data would apply only to that specific back end instance.

**Edit ends**

I am about to try splitting a development Access database and I am confident that it will be a straightforward process. However, further down the line, I would like to implement a split with links between some of the back-end tables or even so that some of the back-end tables are shared. I have tried to find information on the viability of this but so far, all I can find is help on redirecting a front end to different back-end data and help on creating different front-ends to view self-contained back-end data.

My future scenario is this:

I want a few different sets of back end data; one full nationwide set, others restricted to data imported from source A, source B etc. All of these would be production data options available to the user and the structure would be identical for all of them. While the table and query structure is identical, the way the data is presented, within some of the form/report fields, differs from one source to another and any attempt to present data from all sources together would confuse users. I have thought about translating the various representations into a common format but that would lose some information detail.

I also want a production front end plus at least one development/test front end. The former should allow the user to attach to any of the back-end production data sets and the dev/test front ends should allow attachment to anything, with the constraint that any dev front end should match the structure of a matching dev back end. It is possible that multiple dev front-end/back-end pairs will be required, depending on simultaneous structural trials. Again, though it might involve careful version control, I am fairly confident that it will work easily enough.

So, my problem: I would like some of the back-end physical tables to be shared between all of the production back-end data sets. This is because a few of the tables are very structurally stable and their data will be common to all production versions and altered only by admin users. I want to allow admin users to amend/add/delete data in these stable production tables just once, with their updates shared across all production back ends. At the worst, admin users would have to make such amendments in each of the back end data sets which obviously introduces the likelihood of mismatches between the various back end data sets - coffee anyone? Now where was I?

I suppose I could write something to update data across all the back end tables but that isn't ideal, though not worst case.

I could add to some of the tables a "dataset" field and extend my forms, queries, reports etc to take the dataset into account, thereby just having a single production data set but that just feels cheap and not very robust; moreover, it would probably degrade performance.

Is there any way, given the circumstances I describe above, that I can have the back-end data share a few physical tables? Not all, just a few of them?

I hope I have described the problem well enough (possibly with too much detail) so that someone who has had this problem in the past can point me to a solution.

Comment: Actually, you just have the front ends link to that common database. No need to share between the back ends. One of the great features of Access is that you can link to multiple back ends. You  can't link to a link, but the back ends don't need to share that common data, you simply point the front ends to that one common table and the problem is solved.

Comment: I completely agree with Albert's recommendation for Access, but honestly (and no offense) the long explanation is not clear and it seems overly complicated.  However, it is worth noting that enterprise database systems support distributed databases with various types of replication and synchronization. I like your confidence, but if your needs really do evolve into requiring something more complex, it will not be so easy to design and implement this on your own as you state. First try Albert's simple schema and study up on what more robust database systems can offer you in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. A table belongs to one file.

You can create a link to that table from one or several other files. These will normally be frontends, but you can create a link in a backend file as well, though that makes little sense as you have to open the backend to read the linked table, which is what you normally don't do with a backend file.